# JAXB 2.x : Marshalling puts element value twice into the XML

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, eclipselink, moxy

For some reason, all values of an element gets written twice.
My test case is very simple:

```
package test;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class TestBean {

    private String name = null;

    @XmlElement(name="lastname")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Then I marshall the document to the filesystem into an XML:

```
    TestBean object = new TestBean();
    object.setName("abc ");
    Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE );
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    m.marshal(object, new File("test.xml"));
```

And the resulting XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <lastname>abc abc </lastname>
</root>
```

For simplicity I removed the package-info.java file with the namespace definitions.

The implementation I am using is org.eclipse.persistence.moxy 2.1.2:
the jaxb.properties file in the package folder contains this line:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known MOXy issue that has been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.3.0 stream.  An EclipseLink 2.3.0 download can be obtained here:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

The workaround for EclipseLink 2.1.2 is to use another access type, or to annotate the corresponding field with @XmlTransient:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class TestBean {

    @XmlTransient
    private String name = null;

    @XmlElement(name="lastname")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, yesterday I applied a workaround by using XmlAccessType.FIELD and it worked as expected.

Comment: Hi Blaise, is there an RSS feed I can subscribe to in order to know when 2.3.0 gets final? nightly builds are not a candidate for productive systems.

Comment: Just tested with Eclipse Link 2.4.1 and only string1 and string get marshalled... I thought this has been fixed after 2.1.2 ?

Comment: @basZero - Could you provide more details on what you are seeing?

Comment: I will write a new question, as it slightly differs with my current demo code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your test and it gives the correct output for me:

```
<root>
    <lastname>abc </lastname>
</root>
```

It could be the JAXB2 implementation (moxy in your case vs native JDK1.6 based JAXB2 for my test).

Comment: Yes this is a known MOXy bug, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817275/jaxb-2-x-marshalling-puts-element-value-twice-into-the-xml/4817479#4817479

Comment: Thanks for testing, it is obviously a MOXy issue